# Is there a way to select only certain fields from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a performance issue of a function, that takes 15sec to response, which makes a request to firebase for all documents that are
`"ErrorID" "==" "0"`
The problem is that there are many documents and they are kind of very large objects, and I only need **TWO FIELDS** `(Order and Amount)` of each document, there are any way to request only those two fields that accomplish the condition?

Something like :

```
firestore.collection("purchases").where("ErrorID", "==", "0").get(Order, Amount);
```

The function that im talking about:

```
const totalEarn = async (req, res, next) => {
  const DAY = 86400000;
  const WEEK = 604800016;
  const MONTH = 2629800000;

  try {
    let snap = await firestore.collection("purchases").where("ErrorID", "==", "0").get(); // CONDITION
    let totalToday = 0;
    let totalYesterday = 0;
    let totalLastWeek = 0;
    let totalLastMonth = 0;
    let now = Date.now();
    let Yesterday = now - 86400000;

    await snap.forEach((doc) => { // THIS FOR EACH TAKES TOO MUCH TIME
      let info = doc.data();
      let time = info.Order.split("-")[2]; // FIRESTORE FIELD -> ORDER
      let amount = info.AmountEur * 1; // FIRESTORE FIELD -> AMOUNT

      if (time > now - DAY) {
        totalToday = totalToday + amount;
      }
      if (time < now - DAY && time > Yesterday - DAY) {
        totalYesterday = totalYesterday + amount;
      }
      if (time > now - WEEK) {
        totalLastWeek = totalLastWeek + amount;
      }
      if (time > now - MONTH) {
        totalLastMonth = totalLastMonth + amount;
      }
    });

    res.send({
      status: true,
      data: {
        totalToday: totalToday.toFixed(2),
        totalYesterday: totalYesterday.toFixed(2),
        totalLastWeek: totalLastWeek.toFixed(2),
        totalLastMonth: totalLastMonth.toFixed(2),
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(410).send({
      status: false,
      error: "some error occured counting the numbers",
      e: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

The document im talking about

[image: The document im talking about]

Comment: Hey, did this help your performance issue? 
@dante-allievi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use [Firestore Node.JS client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore) or Firebase Admin SDK, then you can use [`select()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#select) to select fields:

```
import { Firestore } from "@google-cloud/firestore";

const firestore = new Firestore();

const snap = firestore
  .collection("purchases")
  .where("ErrorID", "==", "0")
  .select("Order", "Amount")
  .get();
```

Comment: Do you know if I use the select() statement to select only 5 out of 15 fields in a Document, do I save 10 read requests or does it count as one read request?

Comment: @Peter 1 document = 1 read. Select has no impact here.

Comment: Hey. This select() works fine. Is there any way to get the fields from an array or abject? Thanks.

Comment: Select only works on the top-level fields. There is not something like a dot-notation to select partial data on individual properties. If you have large documents and frequently only need a small bit of them, that might be a sign that you could improve your data modeling by splitting the data over multiple collections.