# How is Firestore's "get" function correctly coded in order to retrieve a single field of data within a Firestore document?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have pasted the user-id of the current Firebase user as the document-id of a Firestore document, and I have given that document a single field and data.

Retrieving the data from Firestore is the problem I have, as I cannot find the way to draft a get query.

I have tried two ways and both of these return that the document has not been found.

The security rules allow read on the relevant collection.

```
final _grocerData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('/grocers/{abc1}/fruits/{abc2}/apples');
```

```
  Future<void> getDetail() async {
    try {
      final document = _grocerData.doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid);
      final docSnapshot = await document.get();
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        final data = docSnapshot.data();
        String grocerID = data?['grocerID'];
        print('Firestore-Field was $grocerID');
      } else {
        print('Result = Grocer ID was not retrieved.');
        print('Current user\'s ID = ${_auth.currentUser!.uid}');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

```
  Future<void> getDetail2() async {
    final document = _grocerData.doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid);
    document.get().then(
          (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          String grocerID = doc.data()?['grocerID'];
          print('Data retrieved: $grocerID');
        } else {
          print('Result = Grocer ID was not retrieved.');
          print('Current user\'s ID = ${_auth.currentUser!.uid}');
        }
      },
      onError: (e) {
        print('Error getting document: $e');
      },
    );
  }
```

These methods always return the result where the relevant document doesn't exist, whereas it does exist, so I am confused as what the code is for retrieving a document.

Can you assist with resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question turns out to be that both of the methods presented in the question are correct and work perfectly - they are indeed examples of how Firestore's "get" function can be properly called.

The problem at the time of this question was primarily that Firestore can ignore documents which exist, and return that they do not exist when in fact they do.  And so the real question was not about Firestore's "get" function, it was about Firestore's ".exists" function.

The underlying question has been answered by findings expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000289/firestore-returns-false-to-if-document-exists-when-the-document-does-exist/78000708?noredirect=1#comment137511250_78000708).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure wahts are your intension are when you say ***"How is Firestore's "get" function correctly coded in order to retrieve a single field of data within a Firestore document?*"**

please clarify it

are you want to know how to query just a single field with in the document and don't want to pull all of the document ?

if so then : you can't pull just a single field you have to query the whole document and from there you extract what you are interested in .how ever for server side work you can use [Query.html#select](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#select) .also go through  read  [is-there-a-way-to-select-only-certain-fields-from-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511498/is-there-a-way-to-select-only-certain-fields-from-firestore)

> you use Firestore Node.JS client or Firebase Admin SDK, then you can
> use select() to select fields:

but if you are intrested in a document fied value and understand the how the document are being query.then look at following flocks might be helpful.

```
Future<void> getDetail2() async {

 try{

  let documentId=await _auth.currentUser!.uid +''; // <-- pass document ID here in it.


  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('grocers').doc('FhLH7MwkSVnNyi9BX7us').collection('fruits').doc('alWSbPkzzC9rbL1e2xy6').collection('apples').doc('cGr1Fh8d9Pgl9VJ2UzbeBVmRbhk2').get();
  //if document is in nested collection use this way--> await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName1').doc('documentId1').collection('collectionName2').doc('documentId2').get();

if(snapshot.exists) {
Map<String, dynamic>? data =await snapshot.data();
String grocerID = data?['grocerID']; // <-- pass the field key here to extract from the data and use data as your logic flow 

print('${snapshot.id} => ${snapshot.data()}+ the field grocerID :${grocerID}'); 

   return data['grocerID'];
}else{
  print(' document shot faild or not exist for document ID : ${documentId} check the path you passed to it'); 
return false 
}

}on Exception catch(e) {
  print(e);
}

}
```

fore better understanding go through [get-data#dart_1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_1)

**EDIT points to consider :**

you used `the final _grocerData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('/grocers/{abc1}/fruits/{abc2}/apples');` which is wrong 1st it used the type `final` so it can't be change or reuse with different paremters .
also the way you are trying to query is worng

**WRONG -** `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('/grocers/{abc1}/fruits/{abc2}/apples');`

**Right -**

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionName").doc("documentID_name")`

read [get-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: Thanks again.  I think I understand what you mean, and I was working with the wrong impression.  I thought that the "get" function (which requests a field) was able to return the data at the specified field where a specific document has been pointed to.  But this confused me when the expected data was not retrieved/confirmed.  If instead I view the "get" function as returning a DocumentSnapshot object, I can further treat the object to extract data from it.  In my question, I didn't specify the field, so I will also see if it makes any difference.

Comment: please refer to the comment in the above code block if helps ,let me know any.

Comment: Okay, shall try this now .....

Comment: The code would compile except for this line "Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();" ... Flutter says, "A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'."

Comment: try now and if you are not going to use `Map` then you can just remove that as so far i think you are intent to use the `String grocerID = data?['grocerID']` but please verify the updated code so that it will we helpful for other .

Comment: I mean that every other line of the code works except for that one, and as a result Flutter will not compile/run the code - so I can't test for whether it works.

Comment: Could you check on your side whether you can get "true" or a "yes" for if doc exists please?  If so, what is the code?  I am seeing that Flutter says that the doc/docSnapshot does not exist, and so the if-route is always the unwanted route.

Comment: did you pass the path correctly ? as of not  i think your path is `/grocers/{abc1}/fruits/{abc2}/apples` so your query should be something like `DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('grocers').doc(abc1).collection('fruits').doc(abc2).get();` . i also edited the `if/else` and `try/catch` for better handling and locating the cause if any faced ,try it now

Comment: Best clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000289/firestore-returns-false-to-if-document-exists-when-the-document-does-exist) where the document is displayed alongside the reference.  With thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256901/discussion-between-rainy-sidewalks-and-mathems32).

Answer (score 0):

> How is Firestore's "get" function correctly coded to retrieve a single field of data within a Firestore document?

When you call `get()` on a document, you read/download the entire content of the document along with all the fields that exist inside it. You can indeed select from the `snapshot` object only the fields you are interested in, but that doesn't mean that you aren't downloading the *entire* document. So there is no way you can select which fields to read from within the document using the web or mobile SDKs. There are, however, two solutions for this situation.

The first one would be to use [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore). This means that you should copy the fields that you are interested in, in another document, in a new collection, and then query that collection instead of the original one. In this way, you'll get documents that will contain *only* the important fields rather than all fields of the document. So you'll save a lot of bandwidth and resources. If you're new to NoSQL databases, this might sound some kind of weird, but it's actually a quite common practice.

The second solution, as also @Rainysidewalks mentioned in his answer, is to use the [Firestore Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore) client or [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin). In this way you'll be able to use [select()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#select) as in the below example:

```
import { Firestore } from "@google-cloud/firestore";

const firestore = new Firestore();

const snap = firestore
  .collection("yourCollRef")
  .select("grocerID", "OtherField") //
  .get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  In my case, which is a test case, there is just one document in the collection, and within that document there is just one field and one value associated with that field.  It's for practice elsewhere.  The feedback from Flutter/Firestore seems to mean that the calls of the first two lines of my code are flawed, because Flutter takes the if-route where doc/docSnapshot doesn't exist.  But a document does exist.  In my case, it might be that the code could be right IF the document was found, but it's unknown because for some reason it isn't found.

Comment: Can you show us that the document exists? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I'm about to write a new question as the basis of this one, and there I will include a screenshot confirming the existence of the document.  A few moments please.  It seems that the primary question here is about why Firestore returns false for if-document-exists.

Comment: That's how it works. If you have other questions that derive from the original one, it's best to add a new question, here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Did my answer for the initial questionhelp? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Your answer may have helped, however, because Firestore returns that the document doesn't exist, I don't get a chance to know.  Why is Firestore saying that an existing document does not exist?  I have asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000289/firestore-returns-false-to-if-document-exists-when-the-document-does-exist) with images of the document and collection for a full view of what could be going wrong.

Comment: I'll take a look and if I know the answer, I'll write to you. But regarding this question, can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, they will help at the latter stage of this enquiry.  I have just now completed the primary stage to understand that Firestore only counts documents that were added via method.  Manually added documents are not counted!  Did you know that?

Comment: All documents are counter no matter how they were added.

Comment: For this question I would say no because it turns out that the get methods in my question were correctly coded and worked perfectly (I have checked).  It was your answer to my other question about why Firestore would return "does-not-exist" on an existing document which helped, and I have given you the credit there for your answer.  Please see the answer I wrote above which leads to your other answer.